# Finding $\int \frac{e^x\left(-2x^2+12x-20\right)}{x^3-6x^2+12x-8}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to prove that $$\int \dfrac{e^x\left(-2x^2+12x-20\right)}{(x-2)^3}dx=-\frac{2e^x(x-3)}{(x-2)^2}$$ without using the quotient rule for derivatives
 $\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)'=\frac{gf'-g'f}{g^2}$ (suppose we do not know the solution)

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: without using $\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)'=\frac{gf'-g'f}{g^2}$.

Comment: Maybe partial fractions? Or can the numerator be factorised?

Comment: By partial fractions the function $E_i(x)$ is needed.

Comment: Partial fractions??

Comment: I think many people are solving rhs remove it from the question so people have the option of only integrating

Comment: Partial fractions is the way to go. Yes it involves the $Ei(x)$ function, but the total sum of these terms cancels to zero, leaving the single term you require.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's ignore the factor of $-2$ for now in the numerator, since we can adjust it later by multiplying both sides by $-2$.

Taking $t$ as $x-2$ in the L.H.S we get the integral $$\int \frac{e^{t+2}(t^{2} -2t +2)}{t^{3}}dt$$

Applying ILATE rule on $\int\frac{e^{t+2}t^2}{t^3}dt$ we get,

$$ = \frac{e^{t+2}}{t} + \int \frac{e^{t+2}}{t^{2}}dt - 2\int \frac{e^{t+2}}{t^2}dt + 2 \int \frac{e^{t+2}}{t^3}dt$$

$$ = \frac{e^{t+2}}{t} - \int \frac{e^{t+2}}{t^2}dt + 2 \int \frac{e^{t+2}}{t^3}dt$$

Using the ILATE rule once again on the middle term in the above expression, we get

$$ = \frac{e^{t+2}}{t} - \left(\frac{e^{t+2}}{t^2} + 2\int \frac{e^{t+2}}{t^3}dt\right) + 2 \int \frac{e^{t+2}}{t^3}dt$$

So the answer is

$$ = \frac{e^{t+2}}{t} - \frac{e^{t+2}}{t^2}$$

Now replace $t = x-2$ in the above equation

$$\frac{e^{x}(x-3)}{(x-2)^2}$$

Now just multiply LHS and RHS by $-2$ to get the desired form.

**Q.E.D.**

Comment: the function $E_i(x)$ is needed.

Comment: What is $E_{i}(x)$ ? I have not used it.

Answer (score 2):

If we already know the RHS (and if you don't want to use the quotient rule) you can simply do this -

Let $$t = - \frac{2e^x(x-3)}{(x-2)^2}$$

Taking $\log$ on both sides of the above equation, we get.

$$\log{t} = \log 2 + x + \log(3-x) - 2\log(x-2)$$

Differentiating the above equation on both sides we get

$$\frac{dt}{t} = 1 - \frac{1}{3-x} + \frac{2}{2-x}$$
$$\implies dt = (1 + \frac{1}{3-x} + \frac{2}{2-x})t$$
$$\implies dt = \frac{e^x(x^2 + 12x - 20)}{(x-2)^3}$$

Comment: suppose we do not know the solution.

Comment: You mean we don't know the RHS?

Comment: yes, we don't know the RHS.

Comment: You ssuma that you know the result. What if not ?

Answer (score 2):

Because the denominatof the integrand is of degree $3$, let us assume that the integral is $$\frac{e^x P_n(x)}{(x-2)^2}$$ in which $P_n(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$.

Now compute the derivative $$\frac d {dx}\Big(\frac{e^x P_n(x)}{(x-2)^2}\Big)=\frac{e^x \left((x-2) P'(x)+(x-4) P(x)\right)}{(x-2)^3}$$ So, the numerator is of degree $n+1$ that is to say that we need to consider $n=1$. So, write $P_1(x)=a+bx$ and replace; this gives $$(x-2) P'(x)+(x-4) P(x)=-(4 a+2 b)+x (a-3 b)+b x^2$$ and this must be equal to $-2x^2+12x-20$.

Compare the coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

The integral is of the form 
\begin{equation*}
\int \left( \frac{-2x^{2}+12x-20}{(x-2)^{3}}\right) e^{x}dx=\int h(x)e^{x}dx.
\end{equation*} 
This form recalls the well-known formula 
\begin{equation*}
\int \left( f^{\prime }(x)+f(x)\right) e^{x}dx=f(x)e^{x}+C.
\end{equation*} 
The proof of a more general formula maybe found at

[Proof for formula $\int e^{g(x)}[f'(x) + g'(x)f(x)] dx = f(x) e^{g(x)}+C$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472748/proof-for-formula-int-egxfx-gxfx-dx-fx-egx/1472751#1472751)

So we are done if we find a function $f(x)$ such that 
\begin{equation*}
h(x)=\frac{-2x^{2}+12x-20}{(x-2)^{3}}=f^{\prime }(x)+f(x).
\end{equation*} 
In what follows, I will show that $f(x)=\frac{-2(x-3)}{(x-2)^{2}}$ and
therefore 
\begin{equation*}
\int \left( \frac{-2x^{2}+12x-20}{(x-2)^{3}}\right) e^{x}dx=\left(
f(x)\right) e^{x}+C=\frac{-2(x-3)}{(x-2)^{2}}e^{x}+C.
\end{equation*} 
$\color{red}{\bf Problem:}$ We want to write $\frac{-2x^{2}+12x-20}{(x-2)^{3}}$ as $ 
f^{\prime }(x)+f(x)$ and $f(x)$ is to be determined.

First, divide $-2x^{2}+12x-20$ by $(x-2)^{2}.$ We get 
\begin{equation*}
-2x^{2}+12x-20=-2(x-2)^{2}+4x-12
\end{equation*} 
then 
\begin{equation*}
\frac{-2x^{2}+12x-20}{(x-2)^{3}}=\frac{-2(x-2)^{2}+4x-12}{(x-2)^{3}}=\frac{-2 
}{x-2}+\frac{4x-12}{(x-2)^{3}}.
\end{equation*} 
Now, let 
\begin{equation*}
f_{1}(x)=\frac{-2}{x-2},\ \ \ \ \ \ \ then\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ f_{1}^{\prime }(x)= 
\frac{2}{(x-2)^{2}}
\end{equation*} 
and add and subtract it derivative 
\begin{equation*}
\frac{-2x^{2}+12x-20}{(x-2)^{3}}=\left( f_{1}(x)+f_{1}^{\prime }(x)\right) - 
\frac{2}{(x-2)^{2}}+\frac{4x-12}{(x-2)^{3}}=\left( f_{1}(x)+f_{1}^{\prime
}(x)\right) +\frac{2x-8}{(x-2)^{3}}
\end{equation*}
Now repeat the same procedure but with the new and reduced fraction $\frac{2x-8}{ 
(x-2)^{3}}.$ So, divide $2x-8$ by $(x-2)$ to obtain $2x-8=2(x-2)-4$, then 
\begin{equation*}
\frac{2x-8}{(x-2)^{3}}=\frac{2(x-2)-4}{(x-2)^{3}}=\frac{2}{(x-2)^{2}}-\frac{4 
}{(x-2)^{3}}.
\end{equation*} 
Now let 
\begin{equation*}
f_{2}(x)=\frac{2}{(x-2)^{2}},
\end{equation*} 
and add and subtract its derivative $f_{2}^{\prime }(x)=\frac{-4}{(x-2)^{3}}.$
\begin{equation*}
\frac{2x-8}{(x-2)^{3}}=\left( f_{2}(x)+f_{2}^{\prime }(x)\right)
-f_{2}^{\prime }(x)-\frac{4}{(x-2)^{3}}=\left( f_{2}(x)+f_{2}^{\prime
}(x)\right)
\end{equation*}
Therefore 
\begin{equation*}
\frac{-2x^{2}+12x-20}{(x-2)^{3}}=\left( f_{1}(x)+f_{1}^{\prime }(x)\right)
+\left( f_{2}(x)+f_{2}^{\prime }(x)\right)
=(f_{1}(x)+f_{2}(x))+(f_{1}(x)+f_{2}(x))^{\prime }
\end{equation*} 
It suffices to take 
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=f_{1}(x)+f_{2}(x)=\frac{-2}{x-2}+\frac{2}{(x-2)^{2}}=\frac{-2(x-3)}{ 
(x-2)^{2}}.
\end{equation*} 
The integral is

\begin{equation*}
\int \left( \frac{-2x^{2}+12x-20}{(x-2)^{3}}\right) e^{x}dx=\left(
f(x)\right) e^{x}+C=\frac{-2(x-3)}{(x-2)^{2}}e^{x}+C. \ \ \color{red} 
 \blacksquare
\end{equation*}